# How to get aggregated term vector in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, indexing, aggregate

I am new to elasticsearch. I am trying to get the total word frequency count of a set of documents, but I cannot seem to figure it out in elasticsearch. I know there is a document count functionality using aggregation. And with a term vector, I can find the frequency of a term in a document, but what about finding the total frequency of terms in a set of documents?

Term vector for a single document:

```
GET /test/product/3/_termvector
```

Aggregated document count:

```
GET /test/product/_search?pretty=true
{
  "size" : 0,
  "query" : {
    "match_all" : {}
  },
  "aggs" : {
    "phrases" : {
      "terms" : {
        "field" : "title",
        "size"  : 10000  
      }
    }
  }
}
```